# Why can I log in successfully with the old and new password after I change the password?

Tags: dolphindb

I run the following scripts in DolphinDB GUI:

```
login("admin", "123456")
changePwd("123456", "888888")
logout();
```

Then I log in with the new password. I run the following script again:

```
login("admin", "123456")
```

There is no error. Does it mean that the old password is still valid?

Answer (score 1):

In DolphinDB, the first time you connect to the node to access and manage the database requires permissions, so you need to use the login function for user login. It is invalid to execute the login function after you have logged in.